# Can I change the submit path the record identification creates for a form builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the scaffold-generated _form partial.  The form_builder submit section looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@party) do |f| %>

...

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

This partial gets used in several views, but for `update`, it sends the PUT to an URL that contains the record ID.  That's not what I want (the model contains a token field that should be used instead).  My routes are correct, but if I'm understanding things correctly, **record identification** is creating this URL.  Can I change that, or do I need to move the submit section out of the partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is simply that you don't want to use the numeric, DB ID in the url, consider either:

- [Using `to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/to_param), or
- Something like [friendly_id](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id)

Comment: Both of those bear investigation.  I had a feeling I was re-inventing the wheel, and friendly_id looks like what I had in mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
<%= for_for(@party, url: the_url) do |f| %>
```

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Comment: Yes, that would work, but then my _form partial would only work for that view.  I was trying to find a way to make it work for all the views like it would if I were using the ID.  I'll probably end up going down this road, tough.  Thanks.